# Ode45 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ode45

I'm quite new to MATLAB and im trying to integrate two functions using the [`ode45()`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) function. My code:

```
[w,x] = ode45( @(w,x) ( TSII - TFII ) * w , [0 2], 0 );
```

Where **`TSII`** and **`TFII`** are column vectors 1x151 containing the values of my two functions. **`w`** does not have any value yet, but I've tried making it a column vector full of zeroes length 1x151 and that did not solve my problem.

I get the following error message:

> `@(W,X)(TSII-TFII)*W returns a vector of length 151, but the length of initial conditions vector is 1`.

The vector returned by `@(W,X)(TSII-TFII)*W` and the initial conditions vector must have the same number of elements.

Is it possible to change the initial conditions vector to the same length as `TSII` and `TFII` ?

Or, should I use a loop with `ode45()` inside to make the 151 values?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing a bit, but give it a try:

`ode45()` would like your anonymous function `@(w,x)` to interpolate the function value at position `x`. If TSII and TFII are tabular function values as you write, it will not return the expected result.

You should use something like [`interp1(TSII,x)`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) instead of `TSII`. your function should look like:

```
@(w,x) ( interp1(TSII,x) - interp1(TFII,x) ) .* w
```

Also note the `.*` for the element wise multiplication.